# On keypress control position of <div> in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJaB8/1/).

How do I listen for a keypress globally and change a specific key's value?

*E.g.*

> on keypress of the letter "a" add +10% to
>   `{{player.controls[0].xPos}}`

**JS:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dippybirdApp', []);
var app = angular.module('dippybirdApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Player) {
      $scope.player = Player;
    });

app.factory('Player', function() {
  var Player = {};
  Player.controls = [
    {
      xPos: '0%',
      yPos: '33%'
    },
    {
      xPos: '0%',
      yPos: '33%'
    }
  ];

  return Player;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="dippybirdApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <section id="game">
    <div class="player" ng-style="{ left: player.controls[0].xPos, top: player.controls[0].yPos }"></div>
    <div class="player" ng-style="{ right: player.controls[1].xPos, top: player.controls[1].yPos }"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: updated the question to have a question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working here**: Check your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJaB8/3/

With `angular.element` you can use jquerylite to select an element and with `bind` you can bind events to the selected element.

Now just pass a listener function and add the players position

```
angular.element(document).bind("keypress",function(e){
    if(e.keycode == KEY.A){ //choose the key
      $scope.player.controls[0].xPos = "40%";
      $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Don't forget to `$apply` the scope, to update the `ng-style`.

**PS**: The fiddle contains a full constant stack of keys to keycodes. check bottom of the js file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular-UI keypress](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/keypress), bind the keycode of key `a`, and call a callback function which sets the position of the desired player.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in your controller you can write:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if (e.keycode === 65) {
     var xpos = parseInt($scope.player.controls[0].xPos.split('%')[0]) + 10 + '%';
     $scope.player.controls[0].xPos = xpos;
     $scope.$apply();
   }
}.bind(this))
```